Access blocked: this app request is invalid
I need to incorporate social login into ping as one of my work assignment.
currently I am facing below issue


I have reviewed redirect URI and it's configured correctly

https://myserver.com/\<environment>/<env>/oauth2/callback

The same configuration is working for the account that I have configured for development but when I configured for QA/Production I am getting above error.
What I have tried
I have created an app (project) using https://cloud.google.com/. I have configured OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and API Keys and published the app. I am using generated client id and client for google login configuration.

Thanks
Manish Kumar

I have reviewed the redirect URI configuration and it seems to mismatch the page where SSO gets redirected to. Updated the configuration and it start working :)
